# How to effect other element with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm new to react and getting trouble to achieve something very simple.
I have 3 boxes with initial black bg-color,

I need that whenever the user click on one of the boxes, just the color of selected box will change to white while the other elements stay at initial color,  if the first box changed color and then we click on the second box, so the first box return to initial color and the second turn to white.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import { CardContainer, Title } from './business-item.styles';
import './business-item.style.scss';

class BusinessItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            isActive: false
         };
        this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
    }

    changeColor() {
        this.setState({ isActive: true });
    }

    render() {
        const {isActive} = this.state;
        return (
            <CardContainer 
              className={isActive ? 'choosen' : 'not-choosen'} 
              onClick={this.changeColor}>
                <Title>{this.props.title}</Title>
            </CardContainer>
        )
    }
}


export default BusinessItem;
```

I'm trying to create this screens:

[image: app_screens]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [lift up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). The buttons are not independent from each other; they need to be controlled all together by their parent component. Something like:

```
class Select extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { selected: null };
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Button
                    selected={this.state.selected === "Dog"}
                    onClick={() => this.setState({selected: "Dog"})}
                >Dog</Button>
                <Button
                    selected={this.state.selected === "Cat"}
                    onClick={() => this.setState({selected: "Cat"})}
                >Cat</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const className = this.props.selected ? "selected" : "";
        return (
            <button
                className={className}
                onClick={this.props.onClick}
            >{this.props.children}</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could lift your state up to track active item clicked

```
  const BusinessItemContainer = ({businessItems}) => {
        const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null)

        return <>
            {
                businessItems.map((title, index) => <BusinessItem key={item} index={index} title={title} onClick={setActiveIndex} activeIndex={activeIndex}/ >)
            }
        </>
    }
```

Then in your component

```
const BusinessItem = ({index, activeIndex, title, onClick}) => {
    return (
        <CardContainer 
          className={activeIndex === index ? 'choosen' : 'not-choosen'} 
          onClick={()=> onClick(index)}>
            <Title>{title}</Title>
        </CardContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: hey thanks! didn't get the " return <> { return }  </> " have not seen this markup yet